# How can I modify the downloaded pdf file name from tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to customize or change the file name that gets generated when calling Tableau to export a pdf for the current view from a web page?

Comment: There is a long hacky workaround to do this but it does the job. The post 
 http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html deals with how to export a csv but I believe this will word for pdf as well. You can rename the exported file to be the same name as the dashboard.